# React Build folder not building

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, terminal, build

I have a simple project that I am working on. I run the 'npm run build' command on my terminal, and even though I don't get any errors, I cannot find the build folder anywhere. I don't understand what's going on & I'd appreciate any help offered. Thanks in advance [this is what's displayed on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrTeV.jpg) [here is the continuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYu5X.png)